# What determines which Blade of Hjaalmarch I get?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've helped the people of Morthal, so now Jarl Idgrod has made me Thane and wants to give me the Blade of Hjaalmarch. Apparently, this blade can be either a sword or a greatsword. Searching the internet for a while, I've found a source that claims it is random, while another one claims it's based on your one-handed and two-handed skills.

I use one-handed weapons only, so naturally that skill is higher and I want the one-handed version of the blade. However, I always get the two-handed one, even after restarting the game a couple of times. Am I screwed or do I just have bad luck and should keep trying?

Comment: If its random, you may need to do some other stuff before claiming the sword to change what number you get from the generator, otherwise you'll likely get the same result every time.

Comment: or at the very least leave the area and come back.

Comment: @bwarner from what I've seen, most random seeds regenerate on a full game restart. (Either exit to desktop, and reopen, or turn off the console). Probably the easiest way in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

It's random.

This should be obvious, given that of the two hypotheses you've seen -  either that it's random, or that it's based on whichever skill is higher -  only one actually conforms to your experience.

Sorry for your bad luck, if you want a 1 handed version that badly, you're going to need to do a bunch of reloading.

(It's possible that the random variable is seeded at some earlier point -  when you start the quest perhaps? -  and that you're well and truly out of luck here. But this seems unlikely for a variety of reasons.)

Comment: the enchantment is random too

Comment: ...or you could try to get it using the console.

Answer (score 2):

#### Type of weapon

From UESP wiki's "[Thane of Hjaalmarch](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_Hjaalmarch#Reward)" article (emphasis mine):

> The reward, the [Blade of Hjaalmarch](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blade_of_Hjaalmarch), is a random, leveled, enchanted sword. **There is a 50% chance that it will be a sword (one-handed), and a 50% chance it will be a greatsword (two-handed).** Due to a [bug](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Lists#Bugs)*, however, maces are also occasionally awarded.

> *The list for enchanted iron swords that do stamina damage contains only maces. (This bug is fixed by version 1.2 of the [**Unofficial Skyrim Patch** (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266)) / [(PS4 / PS5)](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181) / [(Xbox One / Xbox Series X/S)](https://mods.bethesda.net/en/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804).)

Related [USKP patch note](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Special%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html):

> USKP v1.2 - (2012-09-01)
>
> Leveled list SublistEnchIronSwordStamina was populated by maces and has been corrected. This will also cascade to fix various quests that may have called this list as a reward. (Bug #390, 197)

#### Material

The probability of getting a Blade of Hjaalmarch of a particular material is detailed in the table below. It shows what material is added to the list of possible materials at which level. This means that if the player character is at level 20, then every single material added at levels 1, 2, 3...20 are on the list, not just the material(s) listed at level 20.

| Level | Material |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 × Iron |
| 4 | 1 × Steel |
| 5 | 1 × Steel |
| 6 | 1 × Steel |
| 7 | 1 × Orcish |
| 13 | 1 × Dwarven |
| 20 | 1 × Elven |
| 28 | 1 × Glass |
| 37 | 1 × Ebony |
| 47 | 1 × Daedric (5%), Any other material (95%) |

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki's "**Skyrim Leveled Lists - Enchanted Weapons**" article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Lists#Enchanted_Weapons)</sup>

#### Enchantment

The Blade of Hjaalmarch's enchantment will depend on the player character's level and the weapon's material. The possible enchantments and at which level you will get them are detailed in the tables below. (Click the image to view the larger, original version.)
[image]

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki's "**Skyrim Leveled Lists - Enchanted Weapons**" article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Lists#Enchanted_Weapons)</sup>

Comment: this is a big explanation. No votes?